# Vue JS value on change in select option

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to Vue.js and I'm trying to display a html table from some json data with some filters, age and state that are also some json. I displayed the table and made the methods for the filters. What i want now is that when one filter changes the other one changes dynamically based on the results on my json data. example(if i click the 18-25 in the states select i want to display only states that have results for that age)

Here are my filters:

```
<select id="age" v-model="selectedAge" v-on:change="updateStates()" class="form-control" name="age">
        <option value="ALL">Show All</option>
        <option v-for="age in filteredAges"  v-bind:value="age.value">{{ age.age }}</option>
</select>

<select id="state" v-model="selectedState" v-on:change="updateAges()" class="form-control" name="state">
        <option value="ALL">Show All</option>
        <option v-for="state in filteredStates"  v-bind:value="state.abbr">{{ state.name }}</option>
</select>
```

This is my table:

```
<table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name/Alias(es):</th>
                        <th>Age:</th>
                        <th>Location(s):</th>
                        <th>Relative(s):</th>
                        <th>Sources:</th>
                        <th>Results:</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="result in filteredResults">
                        <td class="name">
                            <div class="rtable-name-block">
                                <div class="rtable-new"></div>
                                <div class="rtable-ttl">
                                    <div class="rtable-name"><a href="#">{{ result.name }}</a></div>
                                    <div class="rtable-list disc">
                                        <h5>Aliases:</h5>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>Johnny Smith</li>
                                            <li>Joe Smith</li>
                                            <li>Blody John</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="age">
                            <div class="rtable-age">{{ result.age }}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="locations">
                            <div class="rtable-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><strong>Belmont, MA</strong></li>
                                    <li>Newton Upper Falls, MA</li>
                                    <li>Watertown, MA</li>
                                    <li>Cambridge, MA</li>
                                    <li>Chestnut Hill, MA</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="relatives">
                            <div class="rtable-list">
                                <ul>
                                    <li v-for="rel in result.relatives">{{ rel }}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="sources">
                            <div class="rtable-sources">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><img src="img/seals_state/federal.png" alt=""></li>
                                    <li><img src="img/seals_state/al.png" alt=""></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="button">
                            <div class="rtable-button"><a class="btn tr-btn download" href="#">Download Report</a></div>
                            <div class="rtable-id">Report Id: <strong>{{ result.report }}</strong></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

This is my javascript file with Vue:

```
var vm = new Vue({
el:  "#results",
data: {
    results: [
        { name: 'John Smith', age: '35', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Leslie Mac', age: '24', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Andrea ely', age: '56', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Amit Sarna', age: '23', state: 'CA', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '76', state: 'AL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '67', state: 'AL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '37', state: 'CA', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '76', state: 'AL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
    ],
    selectedState: "ALL",
    selectedAge: "ALL",
    states: [
        { abbr: 'AL', name: 'Alabama'},
        { abbr: 'AK', name: 'Alaska'},
        { abbr: 'AZ', name: 'Arizona'},
        { abbr: 'AR', name: 'Arkansas'},
        { abbr: 'CA', name: 'California'},
        { abbr: 'CO', name: 'Colorado'},
        { abbr: 'CT', name: 'Connecticut'},
        { abbr: 'DE', name: 'Delaware'},
        { abbr: 'DC', name: 'District of Columbia'},
        { abbr: 'FL', name: 'Florida'},
        { abbr: 'GA', name: 'Georgia'},
        { abbr: 'HI', name: 'Hawaii'},
        { abbr: 'ID', name: 'Idaho'},
        { abbr: 'IL', name: 'Illinois'},
        { abbr: 'IN', name: 'Indiana'},
        { abbr: 'IA', name: 'Iowa'},
        { abbr: 'KS', name: 'Kansas'},
        { abbr: 'KY', name: 'Kentucky'},
        { abbr: 'LA', name: 'Louisiana'},
        { abbr: 'ME', name: 'Maine'},
        { abbr: 'MD', name: 'Maryland'},
        { abbr: 'MA', name: 'Massachusetts'},
        { abbr: 'MI', name: 'Michigan'},
        { abbr: 'MN', name: 'Minnesota'},
        { abbr: 'MS', name: 'Mississippi'},
        { abbr: 'MO', name: 'Missouri'},
        { abbr: 'MT', name: 'Montana'},
        { abbr: 'NE', name: 'Nebraska'},
        { abbr: 'NV', name: 'Nevada'},
        { abbr: 'NH', name: 'New Hampshire'},
        { abbr: 'NJ', name: 'New Jersey'},
        { abbr: 'NM', name: 'New Mexico'},
        { abbr: 'NY', name: 'New York'},
        { abbr: 'NC', name: 'North Carolina'},
        { abbr: 'ND', name: 'North Dakota'},
        { abbr: 'OH', name: 'Ohio'},
        { abbr: 'OK', name: 'Oklahoma'},
        { abbr: 'OR', name: 'Oregon'},
        { abbr: 'PA', name: 'Pennsylvania'},
        { abbr: 'RI', name: 'Rhode Island'},
        { abbr: 'SC', name: 'South Carolina'},
        { abbr: 'SD', name: 'South Dakota'},
        { abbr: 'TN', name: 'Tennessee'},
        { abbr: 'TX', name: 'Texas'},
        { abbr: 'UT', name: 'Utah'},
        { abbr: 'VT', name: 'Vermont'},
        { abbr: 'VA', name: 'Virginia'},
        { abbr: 'WA', name: 'Washington'},
        { abbr: 'WV', name: 'West Virginia'},
        { abbr: 'WI', name: 'Wisconsin'},
        { abbr: 'WY', name: 'Wyoming'},
    ],
    ages: [
        { value: '18-25', age: '18 - 25' },
        { value: '26-35', age: '26 - 35' },
        { value: '36-45', age: '36 - 45' },
        { value: '46-55', age: '46 - 55' },
        { value: '56-65', age: '56 - 65' },
        { value: '66-75', age: '66 - 75' },
        { value: '76-85', age: '76 - 85' },
        { value: '96-105', age: '96-105' },
    ],
    filteredResults: [
        { name: 'John Smith', age: '35', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Leslie Mac', age: '24', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Andrea Ely', age: '56', state: 'FL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'Amit Sarna', age: '23', state: 'CA', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '76', state: 'ID', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '67', state: 'AL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '37', state: 'CA', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
        { name: 'David Miller', age: '76', state: 'AL', relatives: ['Dana Smith', 'Diana Smith', 'Test Smith'], report: 'dsgsd'},
    ],
    filteredAges: [
        { value: '18-25', age: '18 - 25' },
        { value: '26-35', age: '26 - 35' },
        { value: '36-45', age: '36 - 45' },
        { value: '46-55', age: '46 - 55' },
        { value: '56-65', age: '56 - 65' },
        { value: '66-75', age: '66 - 75' },
        { value: '76-85', age: '76 - 85' },
        { value: '96-105', age: '96-105' },
    ],
    filteredStates: [
        { abbr: 'AL', name: 'Alabama'},
        { abbr: 'AK', name: 'Alaska'},
        { abbr: 'AZ', name: 'Arizona'},
        { abbr: 'AR', name: 'Arkansas'},
        { abbr: 'CA', name: 'California'},
        { abbr: 'CO', name: 'Colorado'},
        { abbr: 'CT', name: 'Connecticut'},
        { abbr: 'DE', name: 'Delaware'},
        { abbr: 'DC', name: 'District of Columbia'},
        { abbr: 'FL', name: 'Florida'},
        { abbr: 'GA', name: 'Georgia'},
        { abbr: 'HI', name: 'Hawaii'},
        { abbr: 'ID', name: 'Idaho'},
        { abbr: 'IL', name: 'Illinois'},
        { abbr: 'IN', name: 'Indiana'},
        { abbr: 'IA', name: 'Iowa'},
        { abbr: 'KS', name: 'Kansas'},
        { abbr: 'KY', name: 'Kentucky'},
        { abbr: 'LA', name: 'Louisiana'},
        { abbr: 'ME', name: 'Maine'},
        { abbr: 'MD', name: 'Maryland'},
        { abbr: 'MA', name: 'Massachusetts'},
        { abbr: 'MI', name: 'Michigan'},
        { abbr: 'MN', name: 'Minnesota'},
        { abbr: 'MS', name: 'Mississippi'},
        { abbr: 'MO', name: 'Missouri'},
        { abbr: 'MT', name: 'Montana'},
        { abbr: 'NE', name: 'Nebraska'},
        { abbr: 'NV', name: 'Nevada'},
        { abbr: 'NH', name: 'New Hampshire'},
        { abbr: 'NJ', name: 'New Jersey'},
        { abbr: 'NM', name: 'New Mexico'},
        { abbr: 'NY', name: 'New York'},
        { abbr: 'NC', name: 'North Carolina'},
        { abbr: 'ND', name: 'North Dakota'},
        { abbr: 'OH', name: 'Ohio'},
        { abbr: 'OK', name: 'Oklahoma'},
        { abbr: 'OR', name: 'Oregon'},
        { abbr: 'PA', name: 'Pennsylvania'},
        { abbr: 'RI', name: 'Rhode Island'},
        { abbr: 'SC', name: 'South Carolina'},
        { abbr: 'SD', name: 'South Dakota'},
        { abbr: 'TN', name: 'Tennessee'},
        { abbr: 'TX', name: 'Texas'},
        { abbr: 'UT', name: 'Utah'},
        { abbr: 'VT', name: 'Vermont'},
        { abbr: 'VA', name: 'Virginia'},
        { abbr: 'WA', name: 'Washington'},
        { abbr: 'WV', name: 'West Virginia'},
        { abbr: 'WI', name: 'Wisconsin'},
        { abbr: 'WY', name: 'Wyoming'},
    ]
},
watch: {
    selectedState: function () {
        this.updateFilters();
        // this.updateAges();
    },
    selectedAge: function () {
        this.updateFilters();
        // this.updateStates();
    },
},
methods: {
    updateFilters: function () {
        const self = this;
        const interval = self.selectedAge.split("-");

        this.filteredResults = this.results.filter(function (result) {
            return self.selectedState === 'ALL' ? true : result.state === self.selectedState
        }).filter(function (result) {
            return self.selectedAge === 'ALL' ? true : result.age >= interval[0] && result.age <= interval[1];
        });
    },
    updateAges: function () {
        const self = this;
        const interval = self.selectedAge.split("-");

        this.filteredAges = this.results.filter(function (result) {
            return self.selectedState === 'ALL' ? true : result.state === self.selectedState;
        }).map(function (result) {
            return self.ages.filter(function (item) {
                return item.value >= result.age && item.value <= result.age;
            })
        })
    },
    updateStates: function () {
        const self = this;
        const interval = self.selectedAge.split("-");

        this.filteredStates = this.results.filter(function (result) {
            return self.selectedAge === 'ALL' ? true : result.age >= interval[0] && result.age <= interval[1];
        }).map(function (result) {
            return self.states.filter(function (item) {
                return item.abbr === result.state;
            })
        })
    },
    resetFilters: function () {
        this.filteredResults = this.results;
        this.filteredStates = this.states;
        this.filteredAges = this.ages;
    }
},
```

});

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: When i update one of my select options i want the other one to change based on the results. I think it works but the values in the select do not display, it displays empty options